# Is there a way to continuously collect output from a Python script I'm running into a c++ program?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, operating-system, multiprocessing

So, I'm currently trying to construct a c++ aplication that calls for a python script. The main idea is that the python script runs a loop and prints decisions based on user input. I want the cpp program to be able to wait and read(if there s an output from python). I tried to make them "talk" via a file but it turned out bad. Any ideas?

PS: im calling the script using `system("start powershell.exe C:\\python.exe C:\\help.py");`
If there is any better way please let me know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could write to a file from python and check every certain amount of time in the c++ program to check for any changes in the file.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard way to capture the output if you start the program using `std::system`.

The operating system facility that you're looking for is "stream". The standard C++ provides access only to the standard streams, which you can use if you redirect the output of the python program when you start the C++ program. Example shell command:

```
python help.py > cpp_program
```

If you do this, then you can continuously read the output from the standard input stream in the C++ program. There is no standard way to create extra streams in C++, although that possibility is typically provided by the operating system.

Comment: I'm using visual studio and in my project directory i have a lot of files, where should i redirect the output exactly to go to the stdin?

Comment: @JoeJoeZ you should redirect it into the command that starts the c++ program. I don't know about visual studio, but I suspect you'll find the compiled program in a directory named something like "build".